# In The Martian Chronicles, why did everyone leave Mars when the war started?

Tags: ray-bradbury, the-martian-chronicles

I mean, one of the main reasons people wanted to leave Earth was because of the war. Then why did they go back to Earth when the war started? I understand that people cared for their families and friends, but even so, in real life most people won't return to a war zone after they escaped.

Comment: One of the main reasons people wanted to leave Earth was because of the war? I recall that "The Million Year Picnic" was about a group of people that left Earth because of the war. Were there others?

Comment: From day one all the people knew that war was coming, that's why going to mars was such an atractive idea

Answer (score 2):

This book was written soon after WWII and at the time there was a patriotic atmosphere where everybody wanted to enlist in the army. So maybe his thought was that everyone would feel compelled to go back to earth to defend their country.

Comment: Or that he *wanted to promote* an atmosphere where everyone felt compelled to fight in a war to defend "their" country?